# Can't get my domain to work after update with EC2 and Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

So using the amazon AWS services,

EC2 with Elastic Beanstalk I've recently tried making a SSH connection. Due to this I had to update my instance to classic auto load balancing. This changed my instance's IP. So my domain didn't direct anymore since the old ip is still in my Route53, so I went in and changed the IP to the new one, but still no results? Is there something more i need to do in order to get my Route53 working again? Don't know what else to change after I've changed my instance to auto load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you've changed your IP to new one but still getting the old results.

This might be due to Cached DNS which is showing the old results also it depends on TTL (Time to Live) values that specifies how long, in seconds, that you want DNS resolvers to cache the information in the record, such as the IP address for a web server.

So if you want to see the quick results set the TTL value as low as 2 min or whatever minimum is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

When using custom domain with Elastic Beanstalk it is not a good practice to map the domain name to your EC2 instance IP address. Instead, use the elastic beanstalk url created for the application environment. With each new version Elastic Beanstalk will provide a fresh instance with a new IP address, but it will keep the url constant.

It is even better create a A record in the Route53 (A records are implemented in AWS as a proprietary technology that integrates better the solutions) instead of CNAME. More information here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)